# Can Apple watch warn me when my iphone is out of range

Tags: apple-watch

Now and then I manage to leave for office without my iPhone. As I depend on some two factor authentication apps and other stuff on the phone this basically means that I have to go back and get it.

It would be an extremly helpful feature if Apple watch could warn me actively when my iPhone gets out of its range. The little red indicator that watch displays in the top bar is not enough. I need a tap and some beeps.

I looked around the Watch app on my iPhone but could not find any setting activating such a feature.

Is there a way to get my watch to warn me when my iPhone is out of range? An app maybe?

Comment: There is a Notify When Left Behind feature in iOS 15 and watchOS 8, but I can't seem to fully understand it or replicate the functionality. Apparently it even works on older models of Apple Watch https://www.reddit.com/r/AppleWatch/comments/pxxu31/notify_when_left_behind_seems_to_be_working_for/

Comment: @thejunejaster this is the correct answer!

Comment: @MicroMachine I couldn't replicate this with my devices, but glad I could be of help to the community :)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure iPhone is updated to **iOS15** and your watch is updated to **WatchOS8**. The watch does **not** need to have cellular connectivity features.

On your phone, go to **[Find My](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/find-my/id1514844621)** app.

- Select your phone
- Scroll to **Notifications**
- The **Notify When Left Behind** setting is in that box (note: The "Notify when Found" stays grayed-out)

[image]

On your watch, go the the app **Find Devices** and select "Allow when Using the App"

[image]

When you step away leaving your phone behind, you should get a notification on the watch about 5 minutes after the connection is lost between the phone and the watch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an app that does this yet either. Your best bet would be to wait for the upgrade to watchOS 2.

This should enable developers to add more functionality to their apps, including the function you're in need of.

Answer (score -1):

Try the 'Lookout' app. (Lookout.com)

Comment: Yes I discovered that app on the app store a while ago and tried it, but at least for me, Lookout generates so many false alarms (e.g. when the phone lies on my desk and I just happen to turn around in my chair etc.) that it is not usable.